# How printing source code in Android Studio bigger?

Tags: android-studio, printing

I often would like to print my code to make annotations to the code on paper

I choose File -> Export ->  Files oder Selection to HTML choose ->

open generated HTML in browser

...

Then I mark the complete code in browser and choose right-click Print

but the text size is too small

how can I set the text size bigger without losing the Android Studio formatting?

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Now I'm using the standard print window File - -> Print

and change font to Trebuchet MS and size to 8 and set

orientation to landscape - now it works without exporting html

works better for me